# Airport - List of Network is not displayed on startup

Tags: airport

I am having a weird problem. When I save network setting is not available the list of other available network used to get displayed on startup. However from past two days I could not find it on startup. I have also verified Network preferences. "Ask to join new network is checked". More over when I try to connect to my preferred network its showing "connected to unknown" in network airport preferences.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the network you speak of is your Home network, then either the SSID is no longer being broadcast or the network name has changed somehow (one of the kids, power brownout?)

You may have to connect by ethernet and get into the router to fix your problem.

If it is a work network, your IT department will help.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug in Maverick's Wi-Fi implementation and hopefully will be corrected soon - it never happened to me until I upgraded to Maverick.

To see all available networks, click the Wi-Fi icon in the top right of the screen and select "Open Network Preferences". Next click "Turn Wi-Fi Off", then click "Turn "Wi-Fi On". Now, you can drop down the list of networks from the "Network Name" dropdown item and select the network you want.

Comment: The question was posted in August 2011 so I doubt that a Maverick bug is the issue :-)

Comment: Oh, you're right. I didn't even look at the date.